# Make row gutter spacing the same as column spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On bootstrap i'm trying to make a 3x3 grid.

I want the spacing between the rows to be the same as the spacing between the columns.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to give margin bottom to the holding div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) a Column has a gutter width of 30px, 15px either side.

you could define a css class

```
.row-gutter
{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

And then add it as an extra class to your row

```
<div class="row row-gutter">
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to not mess with core layout styles because it can have undesirable effects on other components. Instead, put margin on the content:

```
.row > div > div { /* column children */
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `border` property to not confuse the grid system provided by Bootstrap.

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.row:nth-child(2) {
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
.col-xs-4:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
}
```

It produces such [**preview**](http://embed.plnkr.co/gQw9VvUiGDl5immn3ljm/).